# Decode Mongo 128-bit Decimal to Go

Tags: mongodb, go

In Mongodb I have this field:

```
units: NumberDecimal('1'),
```

Mapped in Go to:

```
Units         float64 `json:"units"`
```

I'm trying to read the data from Go with:

```
    var result dbo.Invoice
    coll := client.Database("hobbit").Collection("customer")
    filter := bson.D{{"_id", code}}
    err = coll.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
            return model.Customer{}, fmt.Errorf("invoice %s not found", code)
        }
        return model.Customer{}, fmt.Errorf("reading invoice %s from database: %s", code, err)
    }
```

And I get this error

```
Error: error un-marshalling invoice F-3945: error decoding key lines.0.units: cannot decode 128-bit decimal into a float32 or float64 type
```

I tried to register the conversion with [bsoncodec](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.0/bson/bsoncodec):

```
registryBuilder := bsoncodec.NewRegistryBuilder()
registryBuilder.RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.Decimal128, reflect.TypeOf(float64(0)))
```

And still getting the same error

Comment: I see your edit, have you tried it without the registryBuilder just to see if it works?

Comment: It worked with primitive.Decimal128 :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
Units primitive.Decimal128 `json:"units"`
```

That's the data type for `NumberDecimal`